# How do i redirect specific tumblr pages?

Tags: html, redirect, tumblr

I want to redirect "http://iancalimbahin.tumblr.com" to "http://iancalimbahin.tumblr.com/home" every time the page is visited.
But when I open other pages such as "/tagged/DigitalArts", "/tagged/photos" and other "/tagged" pages, the page still redirects to "/home".
How can I exclude certain pages (/tagged) from being redirected?

Comment: You may want to clarify what you have already tried to redirect pages, and explain why you want to do so at all. Tumblr doesn't give you much control over its pages, so the solution will probably involve Javascript.

Comment: i want to have a static landing page for my tumblr account such that when http://iancalimbahin.tumblr.com is visited, the viewer will be automatically redirected to the landing page.

The landing page contains links to my different tagged posts such as "/photos", "/digitalarts", etc.

Comment: any method will be just fine as long as tumblr can execute the codes.

Comment: Arvin, help naman oh. Salamat.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Customize your tumblelog and try adding this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.href == 'http://iancalimbahin.tumblr.com/') location.replace('http://iancalimbahin.tumblr.com/home');;
</script>
```

Put it right after the `<head>` tag when you select **Custom HTML** under **Theme**.

Comment: Answer accepted! Thanks a lot. You can view my site at http://iancalimbahin.tumblr.com to see what i've done in my home page. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using location.replace(url) is quite a good idea, but you should also add a rel="canonical" tag to your head section to notify search engines you prefer to display */home* instead the pure subdomain in the search engine result pages.

With this [javascript redirection generator](http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/) tool, you can create fully compatible redirect scripts. This also contains a hack to pass the http referrer under IE. You should also add a html redirection meta tag in a noscript element to redirect javascript disabled browsers too!